# Regex to detect distinct and independent three dots in a string

Tags: java, regex

In connection to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984663/sqlite-replace-substring-only-if-its-independent-distinct-and-non-repetitive), I am trying to build a regex to detect all the instances of independent and distinct three dots (...) in a string.

Decided to write a separate question itself.

**Regex:** [(For testing)](http://www.regexr.com/)

```
/(([^\.]|^)(\.\.\.)([^\.]|$))/g
```

Test:

```
... ......... ...
....... ... ..... .... ... .. .....  
....... ... ... abc ... ...PQR... SQT..W..M ... ...  
ABC ... PQR...
```

**Result:**
Blue ones are detected (although unnecessary trailing spaces detected),
Red rectangle part is not detected,
Orange are unnecessary R detected
[image]

**Expected:**
Final result should only be the `...` without any trailing spaces or `R` as the suffix. The red rectangle dots must as well be detected.

Any correction would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backslash before dot to match a literal dot or otherwise it would match any character since dot  a special regex meta character. And also use negative lookarounds, if you don't want to match also the preceding or following extra characters.

```
"(?<!\\.)\\.{3}(?!\\.)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/4)

- `(?<!\.)`  Negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by a literal dot.
- `\.{3}` Matches exactly three dots.
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by a literal dot.

Comment: thanks that's what I needed, still not so comfortable with REGEX.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: That was a wonderful explanation, would certainly help me understand further. Thanks.